# How can i export a request or collection into excel directly from Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase, postman-native-app

I want request present in collection into excel. How can I export a collection to excel using Postman?
Since I am unable to find any solution.

Comment: What do you exactly want? Do you want to make an excel table from your test results, or an excel table of your tests/assertions?

Comment: @ DieGraueEminenz So suppose I have set of request in postman within a collection. and I want all those collection to be exported into excel and want them as test cases

Comment: Thanks for your comment ..found a way around where I can save  collection JSON  into Excel .

Answer (score 4):

There is this NPM CLI called PTOE,
Follow below steps to generate Excel file from the collection.json.

1. Install PTOE globally using command `npm i -g ptoe`
2. Export your collection from postman in latest format (v2.1 as of now)
3. Type `ptoe --file <collection_name.json>`
4. Excel file will be generated in the same file

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ptoe) is the link to Npm Package.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as pointed out in the responses below another person provided a solution a year after I answered this. Have a look there instead.

Original response:
*I think the short answer is no. You can export to json files which don't really fit well with Excel. It sounds like you're after something and are trying to use Excel to solve it. Why not ask for help with your underlying goal instead?*

Comment: Thanks for your comment ..found a way around where I can save  collection JSON  into Excel .

Comment: @Arka Would you please post you answer in this thread? Maybe someone else is running in the same situation?

Comment: HI Josh , the easy around way I find is like ,1st export the collection  by clicking on collection -Export -Collection v2.1 and hit Export. then save the same in you compute .Then navigate to convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.html and then upload the downloaded JSON and hit on the way you want to download by clicking on either 'Cinvert JSON to CSV ' or ' JSON to excel ' and there you are ...Thank you !!

Comment: Hope this helpful

Comment: it is possible indeed. check the other answer, it is accurate.